# Which modules are used in jupyter notebook when using virtual env?

Tags: python, module, anaconda, virtualenv

As I keep getting errors in one of my virtual environments, I wanted to delete all modules and install them again. I am using anaconda by the way. So I found out, when I go to the terminal and type `conda activate NLP` I have a list of pip modules that I can print with `pip list` and a list with pip3 modules, that I can print with `pip3 list`. Since I have already deleted all the moduls, in both cases only pip, setuptools and wheel are remaining.

Ok so far so good. But when I open a jupyter notebook using that environment and import tensorflow, I dont get an error message. It still has access to it. Where is the notebook actually importing tensorflow from? Is it using the modules, which are stored in some anaconda library or something?

Comment: check where the jupyter kernel is pointing to. probably to the base interpreter

Comment: no, the kernel is actually pointing to the virtual environment

Comment: another question related to this: When I Install the new modules, should I use pip or pip3? and if i mix it up, will the notebook import from pip list or pip3 list?

Comment: then maybe simply create a fresh environment